# How to call subroutines in fortran parallelized by MPI?

Tags: fortran, call, mpi, subroutine

My problem is that I don't know how to call subroutines when I use mpi scheme in Fortran.
I have written this small code named TRY.f90 in which there is a subroutine named CONCENTRATION.f90. How should I change CONCENTRATION.f90 in order to make the code works?

```
PROGRAM TRY
USE MPI

integer status(mpi_status_size)
INTEGER                 I, J, K, II, IERR, MY_ID, NUM_PROCS, PSP
INTEGER , PARAMETER             :: GRIDX =64, GRIDY=64 
REAL    , DIMENSION(gridx,gridy)    :: PSI
PSI=0
PRINT*, 'VARIABLE'

CALL MPI_INIT(IERR)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MY_ID,IERR)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NUM_PROCS,IERR)

CALL CONCENTRATION(GRIDX, GRIDY, NUM_PROCS, MY_ID , PSI)

IF (MY_ID .NE. 0) THEN
    CALL mpi_send( PSI(1+MY_ID*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:(MY_ID+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:1,1:GRIDY:1),&
    (GRIDX/NUM_PROCS)*GRIDY,mpi_real, 0,10,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
END IF
IF (MY_ID .EQ. 0) THEN
    DO II=1,NUM_PROCS-1
        CALL mpi_recv(PSI(1+II*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:(II+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS:1,1:GRIDY:1),&
        (GRIDX/NUM_PROCS)*GRIDY,mpi_real, &
        II,10,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
    END DO
 END IF

 CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
 END PROGRAM TRY
```

I am using a subroutine named CONCENTRATION.f90 which is:

```
SUBROUTINE CONCENTRATION(GRIDX, GRIDY, NUM_PROCS, MY_ID , PSI)
implicit none

INTEGER*8, INTENT(IN)               :: GRIDX, GRIDY
INTEGER  , INTENT(IN)               :: NUM_PROCS, MY_ID
REAL*8   , DIMENSION(GRIDX,GRIDY), INTENT(OUT)  :: PSI
INTEGER*8                          I, J

DO I=1+MY_ID*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS, (MY_ID+1)*GRIDX/NUM_PROCS
    DO J=1,GRIDY
        PSI(I,J)=2.0
    END DO
END DO

END SUBROUTINE CONCENTRATION
```

The code currently gives me error since I think I should have made some changes on the subroutine CONCENTRATION.f90. Or I should also change the way I call the subroutine.

Could you please tell me what are those changes? Thanks for your helps in advance

Comment: mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 9249 on node Goodin exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
However, If I remove mpi scheme and then apply gfortran compiler, then everything works fine.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "MPI scheme"?

Comment: I mean if I make the code sequential (rather than parallel) and remove all mpi functions like 'use mpi', 'mpi_send and recv' , ... (means that I use only one processor), the code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your program segfaults because of type mismatch. In the main program you have declared `PSI` as an array of `REAL`:

```
REAL    , DIMENSION(gridx,gridy)    :: PSI
```

while in the `CONCENTRATION` subroutine you use another type of `REAL*8`:

```
REAL*8   , DIMENSION(GRIDX,GRIDY), INTENT(OUT)  :: PSI
```

By default `REAL` is 4 bytes long while `REAL*8` (or `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `REAL(KIND=8)`) is 8 bytes long. So you are giving to `CONCENTRATION` an array that is 2 times smaller than what it believes to be and all ranks from `NUM_PROCS/2` onwards write past the end of the `PSI` array and thus cause segfaults. If you run with one process only, then even rank 0 will segfault.

You should also read about MPI collective operations. `MPI_GATHER` and `MPI_GATHERV` do exactly what you are trying to achieve whith multiple sends and receives here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are right. Now, the code is working fine. However, to my surprise, the code prints 'variable' as many times as the number of processors! I am using four processors so it prints 4 times. This is surprising to me because I typed "print*, 'variable'" before mpi_init().

Comment: `mpirun` performs I/O redirection even before you call `MPI_INIT`. Try running `mpirun -np 4 hostname` to see that it works even for non-MPI programs.

Answer (score -1):

The only change would be to declare `concentration` as `reentrant`.  That could be the default for Fortran 90.  (The bulk of my experience is F77, and `reentrant` is not the default there.)

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: What does reentrancy have to do with a subroutine which is neither recursive nor being used in a multithreaded environment?!